# Understanding the reasoning behind making the approximations of rectangles and cuboids while calculating area and volumes

Tags: calculus, area, volume

In this link https://www.3blue1brown.com/lessons/essence-of-calculus Grant Sanderson said if we unwrapped the ring we can get the shape as depicted below.                    :  [image]                      , but  i made a straight strip (physically) like that and tried wrapping it up to make a ring but problem was that some parts were not effectively matching with the ring structure and whenever i tried to make it more look like ring a bit of the strip of paper will tear out . (dr here represent finite thickness not tending to zero one ) as Grant said there

- So my question is **why** do we say that we can approximate the area of ring to be as a rectangle as such converting it to that form is physically not possible as i tried it , some parts bulges and some parts doesnt makes the ring structure at all ?
- And similarily why is that for spherical shell to we argue it to be approximately a cuboid type for calcuting volume ? As similarly to what i observed from ring its possible that there will be some deformation while converting it to cuboid shape isnt ?

> Why i asked is because i think is that unwrapping it(ring) is not possible as such since its not at all will look like a straight line . I might guess that **straight line strip with diagonal edges** is different from ring structure , its not possible to convert into each other.

- **Note** : Assume we dont know the formula for area of circle and volume of sphere at all . We are as such trying to derive those from the approximations . Those approximations validity proof i needed why we assume so , given the wrongness i posted above in doing so .

Comment: I think this approach to the problem is far better and well explaint https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YokKp3pwVFc&t=47s

Comment: The thing is, it's easy to calculate area of a square or a rectangle. Also, there is no surprise that you could not make a ring out of a rectangular stripe. That's why we call it "approximation". If the error of approximation is relatively small, we can use a particular approximation and make our life easier.

Comment: But i was trying to reasoning behing tjaing a ring as rectangle. That is making a circle as rectangle @trula

Comment: Yeah but how we take that  approximation ? @Vasili